# Django ModelForm - Prevent save in View

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to use a ModelForm to save a model.

**forms.py**

```
class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    weight = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ["number", "pieces"]
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PurchaseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        purchase = form.save(commit=False)
        purchase.contract = Contract.objects.get(number=slug)
        weight = form.cleaned_data.get('weight')
        if check_weight(weight, purchase.contract):
            weight_type = purchase.contract.supplier.market.weights
            purchase.lbs, purchase.kgs = generate_weights(weight, weight_type)
            purchase.save()
```

In the view above, I need to prevent the model from saving if the `check_weight` function returns `False`. 
This function requires some data from the related object. I'm having some trouble figuring this out. What should I do?

Comment: What's the problem here? Your code seems fine

Comment: Hmm I thought it was saving when check weight returned false, but it seems to be working now. There must have been something else going on with my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understood your question correctly, this would work,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def my_form_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PurchaseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            purchase = form.save(commit=False)
            purchase.contract = Contract.objects.get(number=slug)
            weight = form.cleaned_data.get('weight')
            if check_weight(weight, purchase.contract):
                weight_type = purchase.contract.supplier.market.weights
                purchase.lbs, purchase.kgs = generate_weights(weight, weight_type)
                purchase.save()
                return HttpResponse("save success")
            return HttpResponse("'check_weight' returned False")
    else:  # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
        form = PurchaseForm()
    return render(request, 'some_html_template.html', {'form': form})
```